# CSS background image 404 on server with type text/html , 200 on localhost with type image/jpeg

Tags: css, background-image

Problem:
css image is 404 on server, 200 localhost.
IE 11 Dev tools report image type 'text/html' on server, but 'image/jpeg' on localhost

Note root path on server different structure than localhost (one more level)

```
http://localhost:56164/EPT/

https://testapps.myhostname.org/appname/EPT
```

image is declared as background in css class like this :

```
.landingpage {
   background:    url(../../images/Landing_Page_Images/Full_Landing_Page_small.jpg) no-repeat top left;
   display: inline-table;
   width: 63px;
   height: 50px;
}
```

It is referenced in HTML like this (ASP.MVC)

```
<li class="header-li header-li-right">
   @Html.ActionLink(".", "AppLandingPage", null, new { @class = "landingpage" })
</li>
```

Observed in Developer Tools:

Server

```
URL       /images/Landing_Page_Images/Full_Landing_Page_small.jpg
Protocol  HTTPS
Method    GET
Result    404
Type      text/html
Initiator background-image
```

Localhost

```
URL       /images/Landing_Page_Images/Full_Landing_Page_small.jpg
Protocol  HTTP
Method    GET
Result    200
Type      image/jpeg
Initiator background-image
```

Why is the Type different between localhost and server?  I assume that is central to my problem.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: is your server set up to serve jpg mime types

Comment: If the file is not found, the MIME type you get is probably from the error page. Anyway, with the two urls you mention, the absolute paths are not the same; the bottom one is one directory deeper.

Comment: @Pete:  that may be it, I don't have access to the IIS server, but I'm checking on that. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @Mr Lister:  ah, if you are right that confuses the issue, but I'm pretty sure the path is correct.  You are right that the absolute paths are not the same depth, but in the css I'm referencing up (../../) instead of down.  thanks.